# IIS URL Rewrite part of filename as folder

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I would like to use part of the filename as a folder name, my redirect is working but the rewrite does not work, this is my web.config (also has a rule to remove the file extension):

Original: https://www.ipressnet.com.br/v6/client_tracking.aspx?id=x

Rewrite: https://www.ipressnet.com.br/v6/client/tracking?id=x

**THIS WORKS:**

```
<rule name="RemoveASPx" enabled="true" stopProcessing="false">
  <match url="(.*)\.aspx" />
  <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>

<rule name="AddASPx" enabled="true">
  <match url=".*" negate="false" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    <add input="{URL}" pattern="(.*)\.(.*)" negate="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}.aspx" />
</rule>
```

**THIS DOES NOT WORK:**

```
<rule name="RemoveClient" enabled="true" stopProcessing="false">
  <match url="^v6/?$|^client_(.*)$" />
  <action type="Redirect" url="client/{R:1}" />
</rule>

<rule name="AddClient" enabled="true">
  <match url="^v6/client/(.*)$" negate="false" />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="v6/client_{R:1}.aspx" />
</rule>
```

I appreciate any help, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can write RemoveASPx and RemoveClient in the same rule.
The following rule maybe achieve your requirement.

```
<rule name="rewrite rule" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/v6(.*)client_(.*)\.aspx$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="v6{C:1}client/{C:2}" redirectType="Temporary" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="(.*)" enabled="false">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/v6/client/(.*)" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="v6/client_{C:1}.aspx" />
            </rule>

<rule name="r1" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="v6/(client)?(_)?(.*).aspx" ignoreCase="false" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="v6/{R:1}/{R:3}" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Almost!

I removed the 'v6' from the redirect url because was redirected to: https://www.ipressnet.com.br/v6/v6/client/tracking?id=x

And the rewrite still does not work (HTTP ERROR 404)... I have other pages without the prefix 'client_', like contact.aspx, then I don't know if I can have one rule to remove the extension and rewrite to /client/. Thank you!

Comment: Please check whether the request url in your 404 error page is correct.
The reason for v6/v6 is URL rewrite is trying to append relative URL to the end of your virtual application. So you can just remove v6 in your URL or write full URL like  
https://www.ipressnet.com.br/v6{C:1}client/{C:2}
And if you want to remove the extension and rewrite to /client/, you can try above rule(I added r1 rule to the answer above).